# using an ESP8266 shield on my Arduino Uno R3 with an unofficial library

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I'm using the following Makefile: https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile
It works very well and I was able to get my LED to blink.

Now I bought a WiFi Shield which is NOT supported officially by the Arduino WiFi library.
It is the following one I bought: **ESP8266 ESP-12E CC3000 UART WIFI Wireless Shield Board Modul für Arduino UNO R3** - you can find this on ebay: http://www.ebay.de/itm/262525969091?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

What I now am about to do is to include the open source library for the ESP8266 which you can find here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#documentation

Now when I try to upload my sketch it tells me that certain dependencies are not resolved. Like this one here `#include <functional>` which I was not able to include manually. My main problem here is that the github page of the ESP8266 library isn't providing enough information for me how I can get the working lib to use in my sketch.
I need to know how I can get this library to work in my sketch!

Comment: what have you done to interact with your esp through arduino ?

Answer (score 2):

That is **not** a library for the Arduino. That is a **core** for programming the ESP8266 directly as if it were an Arduino itself.

Comment: Hm that makes me dizzy a bit. So I put that WiFi Shield on my Arduino - how can I use this now? Should I use this makefile: https://github.com/plerup/makeEspArduino - from now on to programm my Arduino because it won't work with my plain Arduino Makefile?

Comment: No. You need to find the right library to match the firmware that is on the ESP. If that is the normal aithinker AT firmware then you can just treat it like a normal ESP module. If not then you are on your own. You may be able to flash it with the AT firmware.